# JSTL c:import and x:parse inside of x:forEach

Tags: java, jstl

I am trying to use the c:import and x:parse tags within an x:forEach.

Is this possible?

If not, what is another way to import multiple xml sources depending on parsed data from another xml source?

```
<x:forEach select="$sitemap/pages/page" varStatus="status">
    <x:set var="location_id" select="@id"/>
    <c:import url="xml/pages/page${location_id}.xml" var="location_xml_var"/>
    <x:parse var="location_xml" xml="${location_xml_var}" />

    <x:out select="$location_xml/pages/page/@name" escapeXml="false"/>

</x:forEach>
```

This results in a

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

error, on the x:parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as though this just won't work.

I ended up looping through the sitemap xml and outputting the ids to a new

```
<c:set>
```

variable, then looping through that with

```
<c:forEach> and <c:import>'ing
```

each XML file I needed. So the core forEach will allow this, the xml forEach will not.

I realize this is probably the wrong way to go about this problem anyway, but I didn't get any responses to this question yet. Feel free to offer an alternative!